# VBA not working in 2016 as it did in 2013: suggested file name (InitialFileName) not showing up

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code to export an Excel tab and save it as a new file with a preset file name. The user has the option to review the file name before saving. This is what I have been using:

```
InitialName = SaveString & UniqueString
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName)
If fileSaveName <> False Then
    Export.SaveAs (fileSavename)
End If
```

SaveString is the save folder, and UniqueString is the specific file name, which changes each month. The user clicks Export, the tab is prepared, and the Save As folder pops up in the correct folder with the suggested file name. As long as the user hits "Save," then the exported tab is saved in the SaveString folder with the UniqueString name (with .xlsx already included in UniqueString).

Since upgrading to Office 2016, the UniqueString suggested file name no longer shows up. The Save As pop-up still opens in the SaveString folder, but there is no suggested file name. If the user isn't careful to manually add .xlsx to the end of the file name, then the file type is an unusable "File."

I've opened Excel 2013 in a virtual setting and run the code side-by-side, and it works perfectly in the older version. Does anyone have insight as to why this change happened, and how to correct it?

Comment: This [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/why-does-getsaveasfilenameinitialfilename/097d0282-5ed2-46ff-9c87-bae26b662555) might be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you now need to include a file filter that matches the initial name you provide, so the following will possibly work:

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
                                             FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
```